# Пользовательский value type и проблема с роутингом

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, маршрутизация, asp.net-web-api

В нашем проекте WebApi мы используем EF CodeFirst подход. Также мы используем 2 вида баз данных: SQL Server и MySQL. Все таблицы имеют поле `ID`, но в базе данных SQL Server это поле имеет тип данных `INT`, а в базе данных MySQL - `char(36)` и содержит `GUID`.

Чтобы решить проблему, я создал пользовательский тип значения `IdType` и изменил все классы модели, чтобы использовали этот тип вместо `INT`:

```
public class Document
{
  public IdType ID { get; set; }
  public string DocumentNm { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Затем я настроил DbContext (например, для SQL Server)

```
modelBuilder.Properties<IdType>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("int"));
```

... и репозиторий:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : IEntity
{
  IQueryable<T> GetAll();
  T GetById(IdType id);
  ...
}
```

После этого, когда я пытаюсь идти до, например `http://localhost:7081/api/Document`, он дает мне ошибку:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nGet on type
>   WebUI.Controllers.API.DocumentController\r\nGetById on type
>   WebUI.Controllers.API.DocumentController

Я использую по умолчанию настройки маршрутизации. Вот `[HttpGet]` методы из DocumentController:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get() { ... }
public HttpResponseMessage GetById(IdType id) { ... }
```

Как я могу решить эту проблему? Может ли это быть причиной неправильной реализации `IdType`?

Я создал `IdType` для `Int` значений, как описано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040999/pattern-for-creating-a-simple-and-efficient-value-type).

Comment: у вас неверная реализация контроллера, ну и типа тоже. оставте только метод `public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id) { ... }`, в методе при необходимости приведете к int, свой тип тут точно не нужен

Comment: Мне не нужен string мне нужен мой тип, по моему как то не правильно все время переводить string  в інт + у мене в типе релизована дополнительная логика

Comment: Ну чтож, тогда удачи в передачи своего типа в Get

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли. Насколько я знаю нужно создать кастомной дата байдинг но мне нужна помощь

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть в сторону фильтров, возможно это вам поможет